# Possible to click on link to change class on a different page?

Tags: class, hyperlink, onclick, external

Here is my goal: I want to click a specific link on one page, and on the page that loads, I want to change a specific class. I am aware of the onClick function, but not sure it can be used here. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have access to the code of that pages? because this sounds to me what you want is a pair of greasemonkey scripts to perform those tasks.

Comment: Yes, I have access. I was also thinking: The link on the first page will include an anchor to a specific section on the second page. Does allow any other solutions? maybe the class could be changed depending on the URL?

Answer (score 0):

This jquery would do what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var anchor = '#myanchor';
   if (window.location.href.indexOf(anchor) > 0) {
      //do what you want here, change classes, etc
   }

});
```

you should place this javascript on the second page, change `#myanchor` for your anchor used.

Make sure to include the jquery library in the second page for this to work.